# HTML div border and text don't align

Tags: css, text, alignment, border

I am trying to draw a div with a border and a single '+' character but the alignment is off:

[image]

The code I am using to generate this is:

```
var divPlus = document.createElement("div");
divPlus.style.position = "absolute";
divPlus.style.left = '5px';
divPlus.style.width = '7px';
divPlus.style.height = '7px';
divPlus.style.top = "20px";
divPlus.style.color = "#111111";                    
divPlus.style.fontWeight="normal";
divPlus.style.border = "1px solid";
divPlus.innerHTML = '+';
```

I have played with `padding and margins` but doing so throws off alignment across browsers.  I have also tried using `lineHeight` without success.  Might there be a default that I am overlooking?

How do I get border and text to align?

Comment: Try with `line-height` equal to your `height`

Comment: I have - sorry for not mentioning.  Alignment is still offset.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hx3ysx51/1/

Comment: @Danko, thanks that is getting me closer to the solution.  There is still a space on the top of the div between border and text.  Please move to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made the following work;
lineheight should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/czy2ue6c/

```
<div id="plus">+</div>

#plus{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
line-height:100px;
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-size:120px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an unicode character to make a `SQUARED PLUS` :

Javascript :

```
var divPlus = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(divPlus);
divPlus.innerHTML = '&#8862;';
```

Output :

```
⊞
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `height` of the div and the `line-height` of the `div` to the same value